# Having issues exporting symbols from a shared library ( dylib on mac ) which return c++ smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, dllexport

I am having some questions on how to export functionality between shared libs esp if that shared libs is using managed_pointers and we need to load them up at runtime.
i have two application SampleApplication(executable) and Foo Module (foo.dylib)

Both SampleApplication and Foo module has a dependency on common Module and in common module i have a Interface let say

```
class FooInterface{
   ..
   void DoSomething()
};
```

Foo Module Implements FooInterface or example

```
class Foo_IMPL : public FooInterface {
     shared_ptr<FooInterface> create(...);
     void DoSomething() override;
};
```

There are other modules like Foo and every of these modules have there own factory method(create method) and now the requirement is that i need to dynamically need to load/unload these modules when application needs them. So i made the Foo module a shared lib and wrote a dynamicModuleHandler in the common lib like below

```
 class DynamicHandlerCommon {
    protected:
    
        template <typename C>
        friend class DynamicHandler;
    
        DynamicHandlerCommon(const std::string& libPath, const std::string& absoluteSerializerPath);
        bool load(const std::string& libPath);
        void unload();
    
        bool m_isLoaded = false;
        std::string m_libPath;
        std::string m_absoluteSerializerPath;
        bool m_completed = false;
        void* m_libraryHandle;
    };
    
    template <typename C>
    class DynamicHandler
            : public DynamicCommon
            , public BarObserverInterface
            , public std::enable_shared_from_this<DynamicHandler<C>>{
    public:
        typedef void* (*pFunc)();
        static std::unique_ptr<DynamicHandler> create(
            std::shared_ptr<ManagerInterface> connection,
            const std::string& libPath,
            const std::string& absoluteSerializerPath);
    
        DynamicCapabilityAgentHandler(std::shared_ptr<BarObserverInterface> bar,
                                      const std::string& libPath,
                                      const std::string& absoluteSerializerPath);
    
        void onBarStatusChanged(
            const BarStatusObserverInterface::Status status,
            const BarStatusObserverInterface::ChangedReason reason) override;
    
        void serialize();
        void deserialize();
    
        void getFunction();
    };
    
    template <typename C>
    DynamicHandler<C>::DynamicHandler(std::shared_ptr<BarManagerInterface> barManager,
        const std::string& libPath,
        const std::string& absoluteSerializerPath)
            : DynamicHandlerCommon(libPath, absoluteSerializerPath){
        getFunction();
    }
    
    template <typename C>
    std::unique_ptr<DynamicHandler<C>> DynamicHandler<CapabilityAgentType>::create(
        std::shared_ptr<BarManagerInterface> connection,
        const std::string& libPath,
        const std::string& absoluteSerializerPath) {
        std::unique_ptr<DynamicHandler<C>> dynamicHandler( new DynamicHandler<C>>(libPath, absoluteSerializerPath));
    
        barManager->addBarStatusObserver(DynamicHandler<C>::shared_from_this());
    
        return dynamicHandler;
    }
    
    template <typename C>
    void DynamicHandler<C>::serialize(){
        {
            std::ofstream os(m_absoluteSerializerPath.c_str());
            cereal::JSONOutputArchive archive(os);
            //m_component->serialize(archive);
            //save(archive)
        }
        unload();
    }
    
    template <typename C>
    void DynamicHandler<C>::getFunction(){
        C pFunc = reinterpret_cast<C>(dlsym(m_libraryHandle, "createInstance"));
        if (!pFunc) {
            std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    
        C* pInstance = static_cast<C>(pFunc());
    
    }
    
    template <typename C>
    void DynamicHandler<C>::deserialize(){
    
    }
    
    template <typename C>
    void DynamicHandler<C>::onBarStatusChanged(
        const BarStatusObserverInterface::Status status,
        const BarStatusObserverInterface::ChangedReason reason){
        if(m_completed)
        {
            return;
        }
    
        if(BarStatusObserverInterface::Status::CONNECTED == status){
            m_completed = true;
            serialize();
        }
    }
```

I also created a  new method createInstance in my Foo Module that looks something like this .

```
Util.h  in Foo module 
    extern "C" {
    __attribute__((
        __visibility__("default"))) void*
    createInstance();
    }
Util.cpp in Foo Module

void*
createInstance() {
    return Foo_IMPL::create().get();
}
```

To provide more context i am using extern "C" so that the method name does not get managled up but that is causing issues and i a not sure what my implementation should be in the getFunction in my SampleApplication i.e

```
template <typename C>
        void DynamicHandler<C>::getFunction(){
            C pFunc = reinterpret_cast<C>(dlsym(m_libraryHandle, "createInstance"));
            if (!pFunc) {
                std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        
            C* pInstance = static_cast<C>(pFunc());
            ...
        }
```

Basically if i change my exported function to be like

```
extern "C" {
__attribute__((
    __visibility__("default"))) std::shared_ptr<FooInterface>
createInstance();
}
```

then i get an error stating that

```
error: 'createInstance' has C-linkage specified, but returns incomplete type 'std::shared_ptr<FooInterfaceInterface>' which could be incompatible with C [-Werror,-Wreturn-type-c-linkage]
```

therefore i changed my exported function to look like this

```
extern "C" {
__attribute__((
    __visibility__("default"))) void*
createInstance();
}

void * createInstance() {
    return Foo_IMPL::create().get();
}
```

but now i am unsure how should i cast it back because i get error
allocating an object of abstract class type 'FooInterface' in line
C* pInstance = static_cast(pFunc()); where C is FooInterface

Therefore wanted to get feedback/opinions on if i am missing something here and what is the best way to load/unload a shared lib using dlopen/dlsym if one/some of those methods return smart pointers . If this is not the ideal way what other alternatives i can employ for my situation. My initial thinking was to create an Interface that SampleApplication can cache and then have a wrapper class that implements it, based on whether any methods is invoked, it will load the foo.lib at runtime, get the instance from it somehow and then basically invokes methods on it, Please do comment on this approach as well and whether it is feasible for my usecase . My project is  c++11 compatible only incase that is relevant here.

---------Update-----------
So i also tried my export function to be like this and it kinda work

```
void createInstance(FooInterface* fooInterface) {
    fooInterface = Foo_IMPL::create().get();
    if(fooInterface){ // here fooInterface is not null

    }
}
```

but in the SampleApplication if my code is like this

```
template <typename C>
void DynamicHandler<C>::getFunction(){
C pFunc = reinterpret_cast<C(dlsym(m_libraryHandle,"createInstance"));
if (!pFunc) {
   std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
   return;
}
        
C* pInstance = nullptr;
pFunc(pInstance);
if(pInstance){  // here pInstance is null

}
...
}
```

so my guess is that smart_pointer is getting destroyed after pFunc(pInstance); so still not sure what could be the best option here

Comment: be cautious doing this. Both sides, DLL and calling program, need to be in 100% agreement on what the smart pointer looks like. One little difference in their implementation and you're in for a bad day.

Comment: @user4581301 yes i agree i never realized before today that exporting smart_pointers from DLL could be so tricky , as mentioned in the issue i have tried three different alternatives each with there own set of issues , so wanted to check what is the best pattern that i could use here, it seems like even if i pass the raw pointer back ,i still need to do some logic in the foo module to keep the smart pointer from freeing itself. I guess the Foo Interface will ensure that DLL and calling program are 100% agreement  in what the smart pointer looks like.

Comment: Btw am i going on the right track here and i now need to think of a solution to prevent freeing the smart pointer. Please note that if this is not the correct pattern and if there are any alternatives please do let me know because all these alternatives sees kinda like hacky to me tbh.